# Force Unity to open any file with any program

Tags: unity, launcher

When you drag a file to the Unity launcher, only the applications that are *supposed* to open that file will remain active, while all others become *deactivated*.

Is it possible to configure Unity to ignore that setting and open the file, no matter what extension the file has, with any of the applications on the launcher?

I'd be glad to get an *unsupported file type* from the application when I make a mistake instead of losing a bunch of time configuring what application can open what file (that's because it is no longer possible to add a custom application/path in the *Open with...* menu)

Comment: Well, this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/880798) says this has been fixed. Can you verify if it is working in 12.04 and file a bug report otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: @jokerdino nice to know, tonight i'll update and give a check!

Comment: @jokerdino I tryed with the last update, but it doesnt work.

The only icons that light up dragging a file are these _supposed_ to open that file and, if i drag the file on another icon (non enlighted) doesnt work.

Comment: It reads like the fix is in a proposed update, "unity (5.12-0ubuntu1) precise-proposed" this link talks about installing from proposed, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

Comment: There needs to be some more flexibility than at present, even if DnD behavior is restricted.  **For example**, there no allowed method of opening (to edit) a **.desktop** file from within Nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

It should still work.  Unity only highlights the application that it knows can open that file but it should still open if dragged on a non-highlighted app.
I have just tested this with the latest version of Ubuntu.